# How to use Filament Spatie translatable plugin in custom page

Tags: laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am using Spatie translatable plugin in filament and it works when I use it in filament resources (list, create and edit), but when I want to use it in below custom page then it give error:

```
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
use Filament\Forms\Concerns\InteractsWithForms;
use Filament\Actions;
 
class EditCompany extends Page implements HasForms
{
    use InteractsWithForms;
    use EditRecord\Concerns\Translatable;
 
    public ?array $data = []; 
 
    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-document-text';
 
    protected static string $view = 'filament.pages.edit-company';
 
    public function mount(): void 
    {
        $this->form->fill();
    }
 
    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                TextInput::make('name')
                    ->required(),
            ])
            ->statePath('data');
    }

    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\LocaleSwitcher::make(),
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my blade file:

```
<x-filament-panels::page>
    <x-filament-panels::form>
        {{ $this->form }}
    </x-filament-panels::form>
</x-filament-panels::page>
```

Does anyone used spatie translatable in custom pages, or know how to fix it.

I tried filament spatie translatable EditRecord:

```
use EditRecord\Concerns\Translatable;
```